# Debug Assertion Failed when calling connect

Tags: c, debugging, assertion

I am getting a debug assertion error when I run the code below. The assertion error is thrown when `connect` is called, but I can't see why. What can I do about this error?

EDIT:

I forgot to mention, the connection succeeds and the program completes, but the Assertion still pops  up

EDIT 2:
Including server code

EDIT 3:
Changing screenshot to text error

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...nat\source\repos\Usp\build\uspClient\Debug\uspClient.test.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\lowio\close.cpp
Line: 55

Expression: (fh >= 0 && (unsigned)fh < (unsigned)_nhandle)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

---------------------------
Abort   Retry   Ignore   
---------------------------
```

Client

```
#ifdef _WIN32
int betriebssystem = 1;
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
int betriebssystem = 2;
#endif

#define MAX 80
#define PORT 8080
#define SA struct sockaddr

void request_connection(void) {
    SOCKET sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

#ifdef _WIN32

    WORD wVersionRequested;
    LPWSADATA wsaData = allocator.malloc(allocator.data, sizeof(LPWSADATA));
    int error;

    /* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    error = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, wsaData);

    if (error != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", error);
        return;
    }

#endif

    // socket create and verification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    memset(&servaddr, 0,sizeof(servaddr));

    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   // servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // connect the client socket to server socket
    if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))
        != 0) {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n");

    // function for chat
    // func(sockfd);

    // close the socket
    _close((int)sockfd);

#ifdef _WIN32
    WSACleanup();
#endif
}

int main(void) {
    request_connection();
}
```

Server

```
#ifdef _WIN32
int betriebssystem = 1;
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
int betriebssystem = 2;
#endif

#define MAX 80
#define PORT 8080
#define SA struct sockaddr

void accept_connection(void) {
    SOCKET sockfd, connfd;
    int len;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

#ifdef _WIN32

    WORD wVersionRequested;
    LPWSADATA wsaData = allocator.malloc(allocator.data, sizeof(LPWSADATA));
    int error;

    /* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    error = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, wsaData);

    if (error != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", error);
        return;
    }

#endif

    // socket create and verification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    memset(&servaddr, '0', sizeof(servaddr));

    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification
    if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n");

    // Now server is ready to listen and verification
    if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Server listening..\n");
    len = sizeof(cli);

    // Accept the data packet from client and verification
    connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len);
    if (connfd < 0) {
        printf("server accept failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("server accept the client...\n");

    // Function for chatting between client and server
    // func(connfd);

    // After chatting close the socket
    _close((int)sockfd);

#ifdef _WIN32
    WSACleanup();
#endif
}

int main(void) {
    accept_connection();
}
```

Comment: Difficult to say based on the code shown as it's obviously not a [mcve], but are you sure you're not just hitting the limit of max allowed file descriptors (for whatever reason)?  Just a guess though.

Comment: I used to use `closesocket` instead of `_close` when closing a socket in WIN32.

Comment: @harper That didn't prevent the assertion. It's being thrown when connect is called and before printf is allowed to execute

Comment: Please, [don't post your error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form. You can copy the error text with Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

`_close((int)sockfd)` should be `closesocket(sockfd)`.

Microsoft made `SOCKET` type `unsigned int` or `unsigned int64_t` for preventing erroneous usage of `close()` but as it's seen some programmers force it with type casting and get errors.

Yet another error:

```
LPWSADATA wsaData = allocator.malloc(allocator.data, sizeof(LPWSADATA));
```

passes the size of a pointer, is same as

```
LPWSADATA wsaData = allocator.malloc(allocator.data, sizeof(void*));
```

and should pass the size of the strcut

```
LPWSADATA wsaData = allocator.malloc(allocator.data, sizeof(WSADATA));
```

or

```
LPWSADATA wsaData = allocator.malloc(allocator.data, sizeof(*wsaData));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was calling malloc and assigning the pointer to wsaData. This was causing read and write out of bounds issues. I corrected it with the code segment below on both server and client.

Note that I used PageHeap / GFlags to discover this

```
WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;
int error;

/* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

error = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

if (error != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", error);
    return;
}
```